# Creating delegate function that takes parameters

Tags: c#, .net, list, lambda, delegates

I have the following delegate function in a Unit Test, and it works great

```
List<Record> RecordSet = FileData.RecordSet;
Record result = RecordSet.Find(
        delegate(Record r)
        {
            return r.UserID == "12345";
        }
    );
```

and it works great. I need to perform this search multiple times, so I had tried to add it in a function I could call that took the UserID as a parameter, it's VERY similar, but for some reason, ALWAYS returns null.

```
public Record findRecord(List<Record> RecordSet, string UserID)
{
    Record result = RecordSet.Find(
        delegate(Record r)
        {
            return r.UserID.Trim() == UserID;
        }
    );

    return null;
}
```

I have also tried it by hard coding "12345" in as the UserID value, that also returns null. What's even stranger is that when I am in debug mode and I look at the values in the RecordSet, I do see the Record with the exact UserID. Yet for some reason, no results, yet the same code and the same data in the first function above returns a result just fine.

Also, FYI, I have fond the LINQ solution to the problem:

```
Record result = RecordSet.Where(x => x.UserID == "12345").Select(x => x).First();
```

But I am specifically looking for reasons why the delegate solution is failing

Comment: What do you suppose `return null;` does at the end of your method

Comment: you pointed me towards the exact solution.

changing it to 

    `Record result = RecordSet.Find(
        delegate(Record r)
        {
            return r.UserID.Trim() == UserID;
        }
    );

    return result;`

worked. I got confused because I had assumed the return inside the delegate was returning the function. when in fact it was just returning to the result variable, which in turn was returning null. total rookie mistake. Thank you @conrad-frix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your method always returns `null`, because of this line:

```
return null;
```

Replace it with this and you should have better luck:

```
return result;
```

However, you can simplify this with a lambda expression which takes a `Record` and returns a `bool`. Try this:

```
return RecordSet.Find(r => r.UserID.Trim() == UserID);
```

Comment: thanks Conrad pointed me to the solution above, but I gave you the answer since you had written it out, thanks a bunch.

Comment: +1. @JulieShannon - function unconditionally returns `null`. It does not really matter if delegate is executed or not. Not sure why you insist on need to run delegate at all (on can simply remove `Record result = Re...` line and code will not change its behavior).